# Correção de contador grafico

Tags: javascript, gráfico

Eu tenho um gráfico e meu sistema que preciso que ele informe o valor exato dos resultados buscados.

Devido a muitos dados, os resultados saem assim **1.1K**.

[image: printescreen de um gráfico]

No lugar que esta **1.1K** queria que mostrado o valor exato que seria **1057**.

Aqui abaixo está a função do grafico em *JS*:

```
function ChartConstructor(title, dados, totalText) {
    window.google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
    window.google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

    function drawStuff() {
        var table = JSON.parse(dados);
        var rows = "";

        var array = [["", "Total"]];

        for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            array.push([table[i].Title, table[i].Count]);
        }

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

        var options = {
            width: '100%',
            height: 400,            
            chart: {
                title: title,
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
            bars: 'horizontal',
            series: {
                0: { axis: 'distance' }, 
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart-content"));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        $("#chart-type").val("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tente pegar o valor e multiplica-lo de acordo com a string.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
function getVal (val) { 
   multiplier = val.substr(-1).toLowerCase(); 

   if (multiplier == "k") 
      return parseFloat(val) * 1000; 
  else if (multiplier == "m") 
      return parseFloat(val) * 1000000; 
}
```

Comment: Ou este site pode ajudar também http://numeraljs.com/